# $p$-torsion of class groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, number-fields

Let $p$ be a fixed odd prime and $\ell$ be another prime such that $\ell \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

Consider the number field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ and its extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p, \zeta_\ell)$. Note that $\ell$ splits completely in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$. There is a unique degree $p$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p, \zeta_\ell)$, call this extension $K$. Using the ambiguous class number formula it is possible to show that the $p$-torsion of the class group of $K$ is non-trivial.

How does the $p$-torsion of the class group of $K$ depend on $\ell$? What happens as we vary over all $\ell$? Is it possible that the $p$-torsion of the class group of $K$ becomes arbitrarily large or is there an upper bound (depending on $\ell$ maybe)?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that it is possible to even bound the $l$-rank of ${\mathbb Q}(\zeta_p)$ in any simple way. Experiments with pari in the case $p = 5$ yield the following results for the $l$-rank $r$ of $K$:

- $r = 1$ for $l = 11$, $41$, $71$, $191$, $241$, $271$, $\ldots$
- $r  =2$ for $l = 31$, $131$, $151$, $251$, $\ldots$
- $r = 3$ for $l = 101$, $181$, $281$, $\ldots$
- $r = 4$ for $l = 211$, $401$, $\ldots$

If $l$ does not divide the class number of ${\mathbb Q}(\zeta_p)$, then the ambiguous class group has rank $\le p-1$, which implies that the $l$-rank is at most $(l-1)(p-1)$ (this is due to Inaba; see Prop. 2.4
in Chapter 2 [here](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Eflemmermeyer/thesis.html).